# What is a "sharing group associated with a role"

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

I'm working with Apex Managed Sharing and in the developer guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) for a "UserOrGroupId" it mentions:

- a public group or a **sharing group associated with a role**

I can't find anything to explain what a "sharing group associated with a role" is

Can someone point me in the right direction or give me an example of how to create "a sharing group associated with a role"

Comment: have you done https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_security/units/data_security_sharing_rules

Comment: Oh yes I did, oh ok so "sharing group associated with a role" is really just a public group that has a role as a member?

Comment: @glls Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? I think it best answers my question

Comment: there you go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just allow greater access for particular users.

> For example, use sharing rules to extend sharing access to users in
>   public groups or roles.

However, sharing rules can never be stricter than your org-wide default 
settings.

The [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_security/units/data_security_sharing_rules) will help you understand their use and how to apply them in your org.

Answer (score 0):

If you query the group object with the type ='Role' you will get the sharing groups. This is again a public group that includes all the User records in a particular UserRole

Ex : Select id FROM Group Where DeveloperName ='Sales_Rep' AND ***Type = 'Role'***